# How to edit Excel file (xlsx) using linux shell

Tags: linux, microsoft-excel, shell, shell-script

Is there a way (tool) to edit XLSX files using Linux shell?
What I need is a way to remove the last three not empty rows from the first worksheet.

I know that XLSX is just a zip file, packed with different XML files, which I could individually edit. However, I would like to avoid analyzing and changing the XML files myself, if possible.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

My idea is a python script like this:

```
import pandas as pd
filename=argv[1]
df = pd.read_excel(filename,sheet_name="Sheet1").ix[:-3] ## read the xlsx without last 3 rows to a dataframe
df.write_excel("output_sheet.xlsx") #write dataframe to xlsx file
```

to check "non-emptiness" you can use `df.notna()`

Comment: Sounds promising - will give it a try.

Just to be sure - df.ix[:-3] - will delete last three not empty rows? Because an excel sheet has a lot of empty rows, if you look at the xml file in the xlsx.

Comment: it deletes last 3 rows. empty rows after last non empty row are ignored. For convenience here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html is a reference of pandas dataframe

Answer (score -3):

Libreoffice (and probably also OpenOffice) can read .xlsx files created by Excel. If you don't have a lot of files to process in this way, doing it manually in Libreoffice is the simplest way to go.
If you have a lot of files, and really need an automated solution, Libreoffice is scriptable. See [the API docs](https://api.libreoffice.org/docs/idl/ref/index.html) or start with [a more tutorial introduction](http://christopher5106.github.io/office/2015/12/06/openoffice-libreoffice-automate-your-office-tasks-with-python-macros.html).

Comment: This doesn't work for me, because I want to automate something on a headless server.

Comment: You should edit your question too specify all your constraints / requirements.

Comment: @pipe. It is possible to run LibreOffice in headless mode, is it not?

Comment: @TRiG Sure it is, and an answer detailing how to do that would be a great answer. This is not that answer.

Comment: @pipe calling LibreOffice a "one-off gui tool" is pretty extreme. It's basically the opposite of what it really is.

Comment: Opening LibreOffice in Headless mode is as simple as using the `--headless` option.